# java chrono unit difference between year

Tags: java, java-time, chronounit

i have below code to get difference between two years..

```
long yearsBetween = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(
                customDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(),
                LocalDate.now());
```

my date value is as below

```
customDate = 2022-03-07
LocalDate.now() = 2021-10-07
```

but when i execute ChronoUnit.YEARS.between, it returns `"0"`, but i am expecting `"1"` as return value. i want to compare only years for the given date and get the difference, excluding days..

Comment: The dates you've given are only 5 months apart though.  Do you want it to only consider the year portion of the date?  So 2021-12-31 and 2022-01-01 would be 1 year apart, but 2022-01-01 and 2022-12-31 would be 0 years apart?  This part of your question could be made clearer.

Comment: i have mentioned , that i need to compare only years not dates in question..

Comment: Got it, I was just a little confused by the wording.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ignore the month and day components of the LocalDate, you can just get the year from each LocalDate and then compare them, like so:

```java
// Let's say we have two LocalDates, date1 and date2:
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2021, 10, 6);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2022, 3, 7);

// We can get the year for each object and then subtract the two years:
long yearsBetween = date2.getYear() - date1.getYear();

// This will print 1 because 2022 is 1 year ahead of 2021:
System.out.println(yearsBetween);
```

As a side note, there is no need for `yearsBetween` to be a long data type (64-bit integer).  The `getYear()` method returns an int (32-bit integer), and I doubt you'll ever have to deal with years that far in the future.  We can just use:

```java
int yearsBetween = date2.getYear() - date1.getYear();
```

You can then just plug in your dates where `date1` and `date2` are like so:

```java
int yearsBetween = customDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDate().getYear()
        - LocalDate.now().getYear();
```

Comment: comparing date.getYear() and getting difference is what i did.. this works.. Thanks..

Comment: No need to go the `LocalDate` detour: `int yearsBetween = customDate.toInstant() .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getYear() - Year.now().getValue();` Another possibility would be `long yearsBetween2 = Year.now().until( customDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()), ChronoUnit.YEARS);`